# CakePHP Assciosiations

Tags: cakephp, associations

Allright, lets say I have a `User` and every user hasMany `EmailAddress`s.

I have created the following view, to show a single user:

```
<h2>
    <?php echo $user['User']['username']?>
</h2>
<h3>Addresses</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>   
<?php foreach ($user['EmailAddress'] as $emailAddress): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $emailAddress['address']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Now I want to create in this `User` view, an input box, that can add a new EmailAddress associated to that account. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a form pointing to EmailAddressController/add method

```
echo $this->Form->create('EmailAddress');
//hidden field to indicate which user we are adding the email address to
echo $this->Form->hidden('user_id', array('value' => $user['User']['id'])); 
echo $this->Form->input('address');
echo $this->Form->end('Add');
```

This PHP should create a FORM that points to your emailaddresses/add controller/action pair. In that Add action, you'll handle the POST and add the email and redirect back to this page.

EDIT : Added `echo`s! as @Tim mentioned

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that too, but wouldn't someone be able to tamper this data to add it to a different user?

Comment: Oh come on, right what I was about to answer ;)
Don't forget the echos before those!

Comment: @TimoWillemsen Oh, I thought this was a private screen. If you're allowing only the logged in user to add emails, you can simply get the ID of the logged in user via Auth. Do this in the controller and remove the view variable. So no one can tamper

Comment: Well actually it's both a private and a non-private screen. As an administrator I want to be able to do it, so Auth doesn't work there, since they will be added to my account. But I also want users to add them, and then they could tamper it.

Comment: @TimoWillemsen Not really. All you have to do is check whether the currently logged in user is an admin or not. If it's an admin, take the post value. If it's a normal user, use the session. However, ideally you should be using different controllers/actions for admin/normal user seperation

Comment: Allright, what is your opinion about using sessions for this?

Comment: @TimoWillemsen if it's a user facing page, you should definitely be taking the user ID from the the Auth component. You don't have any other way of verifying the identity.